# Can't make Ionic3 "deeplinks" work

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, deep-linking

I'm trying to use deeplink inside an Ionic **web** application (not a native one).

I followed [these instructions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/) step by step.
But it seems to have absolutely no effect when entering the url (I see the home page).

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(FeedbackPage),
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule]
```

**feedback.ts**

```
@IonicPage({
  segment: 'some-path',
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-feedback',
  templateUrl: 'feedback.html',
})
export class FeedbackPage extends HugoApiErrorsMixin implements OnInit {
```

Accessing `http://localhost:8100/#/some-path` display my home page instead of the Feedback page.
Navigating manually to the Feedback page does NOT change the displayed URL.

*NOTE* : I'm using ionic 3.8.0 (latest) and ionic scripts 3.0.1 (latest)

Answer (score 0):

`3.7.1` is not the latest. You need to install [**3.8.0**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v3.8.0)

It has number of fixes for the navigation related issues:

> navigation: account for condition of toggling one view with tabs to
> another view with tabs (c963745)
>
> navigation: add defaultHistory
> support to ion-tabs (2646ebe)
>
> navigation: unregister root navs when
> appropriate (2bd89fe)

Comment: Hi! Just updated my ionic version to the 3.8.0, but it didn't solve my problem.